# Can I create a custom excel document level ribbon without VS

Tags: c#, xml, excel, vba, ribbon

I need to create a custom Excel 2010 ribbon (document level).
I have no Visual Studio, but have Visual C# 2010 express
If this is possible, please give me some gudelines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the ribbon in Excel or any Office application without using Visual Studio, instead using a combination of XML and VBA.

A good starting-point for customizing the ribbon: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx (The title says Office 2007 but it will work for Office 2010 as well)

There is a free application that helps you design and validate the XML to modify the ribbon called the "Custom UI Editor For Microsoft Office": http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2006/05/25/customuieditor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have Visual Studio, but Express Edition and it shouldn't make any difference at this point ;)

I don't get your point about "Excel 2010 ribbon". I think that this is handled by Excel 2010 and it's part of User Interface of Office 2010, so if you open any Excel file in 2010 version you'll get ribbons. You can [customize Office 2010 Ribbon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942866.aspx) and creating Excel files can be done in a lot of different ways i.e. [using OpenXML](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124), [Microsoft Office Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29). Each has advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Adrian, I want to create a file with vba code inside. And want this file to have a custom ribbon, not standard excel ribbon. Is this possible with OpenXML or MSOI ?